# LIBgdx, detecting collision between by using rectangle.overlaps(rectangle) method in render method gives StackOverFlow error

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to detect collision between two actors so I created two rectangle use {rectangle1.overlaps(rectangle2)} method to detect collision/ overlaps. I want to call GameOver scene when they overlap, so I call overlaps method in {public void render ()} method. The problem is I got a StackOverfLow error. My GameMain class extends Game class and my GameOver class implements Screen class.
Here's my contactDetection method that i call in render method class:

```
public void contactDetection(){

    if (bounds.overlaps(boundscake)) {

        setScreen(new GameOver(score, this));
    }
}
```

Here's my GameOver class :

```
public class GameOver implements Screen  {

private int score;
Game game;
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture texture;
GameMain gameMain;

public GameOver(int score, Game game){
    this.score = score;
    this.game = game;
    texture = new Texture("test.jpg");
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    gameMain = new GameMain();

}

@Override
public void show() {
    game.setScreen(this);


}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(texture, 0,0 ,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    batch.end();

}
```

Comment: I understand that maybe because the method of detecting collision is called every single frame and gives error, i don't know any other better way of detecting collision. Any idea ?

Comment: Your stack overflow is because you call setScreen(this) in show(), which is called by the Game class when you call setScreen() so you've created an infinite loop. Just delete that line. Checking bounds in render() is the correct way to do that.